# Does windows XP support unicode button text in an SWT Java program?

Tags: java, windows, unicode, swt

I have included a couple of unicode arrows in my SWT Java UI and have just noticed that my Windows XP machine doesn't render these characters.

**XP** : [image: Button on Windows XP]

**7** : [image: Button on Windows 7]

Does Windows XP not support unicode UI text or do I need to do something special to enable support?

Comment: I believe it is font fall-back issue. Your system font probably does not have these glyphs and for some reason is unable to fall-back to the one that have them.

Comment: AFAIK I am just using the normal Windows XP font from the "Windows Classic" theme. Should I avoid using non ASCII characters in UI elements or are there some which are safe?

Comment: How do you type the unicode char to the code? Directly or is it some escape sequence? (like \uXXXX or &#XXX;)

Comment: @mchr: I didn't say you use some special font. I just said that apparently this font is unable to show you these arrows and it Operating Systems need to substitute it with something else for these particular characters. This is known as font fall-back mechanism and it seems it does not work correctly. It is possible that you would need to add some key to registry. As for your question, your application is Unicode-enables since Java uses UTF-16 internally.

Comment: Pavel Dyda has right. I tried the arrow char (\u21D3) in W7 (works) and in XP (didn't work). But if you try another characters, which are unicode, but are in selected font (check on character map application), they work pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue here is that the default XP UI font is Tahoma which has a very limited set of characters. This can be seen by opening the Character Map application.

This issue can be worked around by choosing appropriate characters when the UI font is Tahoma. I chose these chars:

```
private static final String UP = "\u25B2";
private static final String DOWN = "\u25BC";
private static final String RIGHT = "\u25BA";

private static final String TAHOMA_UP = "\u06F8";
private static final String TAHOMA_DOWN = "\u06F7";
private static final String TAHOMA_RIGHT = "\u003E";
```

I detected which contacts to use with this single line of code.

```
boolean tahomaUIFont = composite.getFont().getFontData()[0].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tahoma");
```